SUMIFS after dividing each individual value in a row by another individual value in a row
I'm looking for an equation in Excel that would do the following:

For each row in "# Shares," divide by the value in "Annualization Period"
Sum each of these individual values (so not adding up total # shares and dividing by total # yrs) if the employee is "John" and the award is "Option"

I'm not an Excel expert whatsoever, but it seems that SUMPRODUCT here would add up the sum of all the shares and divide by the sum of all the years, which would be different from what I'm looking for:
SUMPRODUCT:
(500+100)/(2+1) = 600/3 = 200

What I'm looking for:
(500/2) + (100/1) = 250 + 100 = 350




Employee
Award Type
# Shares
Annualization Period




John
Option
500
2


John
RS
300
3


John
Option
100
1


Emily
Option
200
4


Mark
RS
500
5



What would be best here?

Sumproduct still works, just do the division before the add:
=SUMPRODUCT(C2:C6/D2:D6*(A2:A6="John")*(B2:B6="Option"))



Assume your data table above starts in cell A1. The most readable solution would be to add a new column in column E, say Quotient, to divide the shares by the period. Then use:
=SUMIFS(E2:E6, A2:A6, "John", B2:B6, "Option")

to get the result you need.

If you haven't already, you may want to look at using tables, for example:

Add another column # Shares per Period (as Neil T also suggested)
Insert table

Select A1:E6, Insert > Table, or Control + T or CMT + T


In the first cell under # Shares per Period enter formula for the calculation by clicking on the cells to the left on the same row; table references @['# Shares] etc. instead of C2 will be filled automatically
Enable 'Total Row' from the Table tab.
Use the Filter buttons


